# Adding a 'Clearing' effect to inline elements

Tags: css

I was wondering if you can apply a clearing style effect to a bunch of inline elements?

My problem is I am working with a set of sibling div elements so I cannot apply any kind of block display to a container or parent element.

Here is the code in question (the HTML cannot change unfortunately, only the CSS):

```
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-alert-option-1">...</div>
Send alert
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-alert-time-period-1">...</div>
day(s) from completion date
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-alert-option-2">...</div>
Send alert
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-alert-time-period-2">...</div>
day(s) from completion date
```

Note there is further input and label content where the '...' marks are but it is too large and irrelevant for the question.

The CSS I am applying is:

```
.form-item {
    display: inline;
}
```

In the above sample I would like a new line represented by each class number, '1, 2 etc'.

Is this possible without altering the HTML?

Any input is much appreciated,

Rick

Comment: Are your divs meant to be nested? Where are the closing tags?

Comment: Apologies I have added that. It is quite a large piece of code, I made an error trying to copy it all!

Comment: If your 'large and irrelevant' code includes any block level elements then you shouldn't make the divs inline - it's invalid CSS.

Comment: what do you mean with "clearing"? do you want to apply clear: left/right/both to them or just spacing them?

Comment: So they are on a new line. Am I mistaken that the clear property is only valid with floats?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I've got exactly what you want to achieve, and why you have to display your divs as inline elements, but you could try with inline-block:

```
.form-item {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
```

otherwise why don't you just float:left them and clear them?

```
.form-item {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
}
```

haven't tested it so it might not work. if you could elaborate more about why you are displaying your divs as inline elements, that would help! thanks

Comment: Inline-block worked, although this was due to the fact that I had to make sure that elements filled up the width of the container and that way they would force themselves onto the next line.

Answer (score 1):

You can clear the Inline-Element with a pseudo block element

```css
.form-item {
  display: inline;
}
.clear-before::before {
    content:' ';
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-alert-option-1">[[Form]]</div>
Send alert
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-alert-time-period-1">[[Form item]]</div>
day(s) from completion date
<div class="form-item form-type-checkbox form-item-alert-option-2 clear-before">[[New Line Form Element]].</div>
Send alert
<div class="form-item form-type-select form-item-alert-time-period-2">[[Form Element]]</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery append to add text to each div.

[append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

Comment: I'm gonna +1 you back to 0, I think your answer makes no sense but only because I missed some of the code in my question. I've fixed the edit now.

Comment: @RickDonohoe jQuery append() doesn't address your problem. Your question is about how to format the display of HTML elements so each new chunk appears on a new line; append() is javascript that adds content to your divs!

Comment: @RickDonohoe my bad then, I thought you wanted to add line numbers when saying this "In the above sample I would like a new line represented by each class number, '1, 2 etc'."